Якорные ссылки на другие разделы (input) на JS
Как реализовать якорную ссылку на фрагмент из другого раздела страницы? Переключение между страницами реализовано так:
<input type="radio" name="inset" value="" id="tab_1" checked>
<label for="tab_1">Основная информация</label>
<input type="radio" name="inset" value="" id="tab_2">
<label for="tab_2">Контакты</label>

В "Основной информации" ставлю ссылку на якорь в "Контакты".
<a href="#M">Менеджер</a> //основная информация
<p id="M">Контакты менеджера можно найти ниже...</p> //контакты

Но при нажатии на ссылку ничего не происходит. Пожалуйста, подскажите, как это исправить!

либо уйти от radio-табов, либо <a href='#M' onClick='document.getElementById("tab_2").value="checked";'> ну как то так... доступ к radio через js тут скорее всего не корректен(на правах псевдо-кода)

@puffleeck, а Вы не подскажите, чем можно заменить radio?

та хотя бы на tabs:target (элемент ид которого в якоре - целевой - псевдокласс :target). .tabs:not(:target), .tabs:not(:has(:target)){display none} что то подобное. либо сразу писать нормальный роут на js, или даже взять готовый на чем то вроде react/vue

Хорошо, спасибо большое, попробую. Код старый и не мой, но вряд ли будет переписывать полностью

Попробуйте слэш поставить перед решеткой

@Arcadiy, не помогло, к сожалению
